# How do I create or access a static resource in my method when test is running

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an apex method that reads static resource files and attaches a copy to each new record created. It executes this line and the static resources exist so it works fine.

```
list<StaticResource> docList = [select id, name, contenttype, bodylength, body from StaticResource where name IN ('SiteVisitQuestions','SiteVerificationForm')];
```

However when my test code runs and calls this apex method it fails. It seems like my code cannot do anything with static resources in the method when test code is running. I can't even do this.

```
list<StaticResource> docList = new list<StaticResource>();
```

it fails when test is running and nothing beyond this point in the method executes.
How do I test code that reads static resources. I can't insert them in the test method. Even tried to use the metadataservice methodology but that is a callout and it fails to even save the test method

Comment: Please edit your question to add the full text of the error(s) that you're getting.

Comment: It doesn't give any errors it just fails and test code coverage stops at that line of code

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically create Static Resources from Apex tests. What you are looking for is mocking this call in your tests instead.

If you have the static resource in the org, you can probably query it using the `@SeeAllData` annotation in your test.

Comment: Yes see all data makes it work I just don't like to do that. Oh well guess I have no choice. Thanks Renato